# How come response headers are not saved after resolving promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm writing a test in Jest to make sure I'm setting the correct content-type and and content-length for my response. I've created a promise, and the promise is resolved twice, but it's only saving the first resolve.

I want it to resolve right after I set my res content-length and content-type, so I've tried taking out the very last Promise.resolve, but when I test, I receive a TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

My Test

```
test("Files are served with correct Content-Length and Content-Type", function(done) {
  var httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
  var req = httpMocks.createRequest({
    url: "public/test.html",
    method: "GET"
  });
  var res = httpMocks.createResponse({
    eventEmitter: require('events').EventEmitter
  });
  var pair = {
    req: req,
    res: res
  };
  serveContent.serveContent(pair).then(function(pair) {
    console.log("as i go in");
    expect(pair.res.headers["content-length"]).toEqual(114);
    expect(pair.res.headers["content-type"]).toEqual('text/html');
    done();
  });
  console.log("before emit");
  pair.req.emit('end');
  console.log("after emit")


});
```

The Function I pass into the test

```
serveContent(pair) {

    const parsedUrl = url.parse(pair.req.url);
    var filePath = parsedUrl.pathname;

    pair.req.on('end', function(){


    if(!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {

      pair.res.statusCode = 404;
      pair.res.statusMessage = "Not Found";
      pair.res.end();
      return Promise.resolve(pair);
    }
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, body) {

      if(err) return err;
      // Set the Content-Length
      pair.res.setHeader("Content-Length", body.length);
      // Set the Content-Type

      pair.res.setHeader("Content-Type", determineContentType(filePath));
      // Serve the file data
      pair.res.end(body);

      return Promise.resolve(pair);

    });
    const determineContentType = (file) => {
      // TODO: determine and return content-type
      // 
      switch(path.extname(file).toLowerCase()) {
        case '.html':
        case '.htm':
          return 'text/html';
        case '.css':
          return 'text/css';
        case '.js':
          return 'text/javascript';
        case '.gif':
          return 'image/gif';
        case '.jpeg':
          return 'image/jpeg';
        case '.png':
          return 'image/png';
        case '.pdf':
          return 'application/pdf';
        case '.ttf':
          return 'font/ttf';
        case '.woff':
          return 'wont/woff';
        default:
          return 'application/octet-stream';
      }


    }

    });
    //read file
    //determine file type
    console.log("right before bad resolved");
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
```

With the test.html file I'm also using, I should be getting a content-type = 'text/html' and content-length = 114, but instead my headers are {} undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the

```
console.log("right before bad resolved");
return Promise.resolve();
```

Your `serveContent` immediately resolves the promise, without ever running the `end` handler.

So, you need to wrap the `serveContent` in promise and return when the `end` method is called, Logically that is what happens also, after the request ends and gets the response then any http call is resolved.

```
function serveContent(pair) {
  const determineContentType = (file) => {
    // TODO: determine and return content-type
    // 
    switch (path.extname(file).toLowerCase()) {
      case '.html':
      case '.htm':
        return 'text/html';
      case '.css':
        return 'text/css';
      case '.js':
        return 'text/javascript';
      case '.gif':
        return 'image/gif';
      case '.jpeg':
        return 'image/jpeg';
      case '.png':
        return 'image/png';
      case '.pdf':
        return 'application/pdf';
      case '.ttf':
        return 'font/ttf';
      case '.woff':
        return 'wont/woff';
      default:
        return 'application/octet-stream';
    }


  }
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const parsedUrl = url.parse(pair.req.url);
    var filePath = parsedUrl.pathname;

    pair.req.on('end', function () {

      if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {

        pair.res.statusCode = 404;
        pair.res.statusMessage = "Not Found";
        pair.res.end();
        return Promise.resolve(pair);
      }
      fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, body) {

        if (err)  return rej(err);
        // Set the Content-Length
        pair.res.setHeader("Content-Length", body.length);
        // Set the Content-Type

        pair.res.setHeader("Content-Type", determineContentType(filePath));
        // Serve the file data
        pair.res.end(body);

        return res(pair);

      });
    });
  })
}
```

**Note**: The way you are using `Promise.resolve` inside the callback function is also wrong, you are returning promise from the callback, not the parent function, it doesn't propagate to the parent function as well.